# How can i search partial part of a field using a list in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list from Names like

```
 List<string> PartialOrganism = new List<string>{ "Arabidopsis", "Elsholtzia", "Elymus", "Oryza sativa" };
```

And a field which is complete, **Table.Organism** some values  like :

**"Elymus elongatum" 
 "Oryza sativa (Rice)" 
"Arabidopsis thaliana"**

How can i have a query like this,

```
Var query =from c in Table where c.Organism.Contains(PartialOrganism) select c;
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please be more detailed on what you want to get. Providing an example (input/output) it would be very beneficial. thanks

Comment: you want to find if Organism field contains any item from list?

Comment: something very close to `c.Organism.Where(org => PartialOrganism.Any(org.Contains))`

Comment: Please see this example `var query=from c in Table.Organism where c.Organism.Contains("Arabidopsis") select c;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you would want a query that looked like the following:

```
var query = from c in Table
where PartialOrganism.Any(po => c.Organism.Contains(po))
select c;
```

This query is saying: find us all records in Table if PartialOrganism contains any string elements which is a substring of c.Organism.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Drew but it shows error **_Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator._**

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to search on all the partial organisms. You will have to wrap your query in a loop.

Something like below where matchingOrganisms is an object you can append to.

```
foreach (string organism in PartialOrganisms)
    {
       matchingOrganisms =  (from c in Table where c.Organism.Contains(organism) select c);
    }
```

Here is a more thorough example for you. Declare a list (this could also be a list of custom objects etc..)

```
List<object> rows = new List<object>();
```

Then add the results of each query to the list:

```
foreach (string organism in PartialOrganisms)
    {
       rows.AddRange((from c in Table where c.Organism.Contains(organism) select c).ToList());
    }
```

This will act as an or.

Comment: It says, In each Foreach step  `AND` query vi next Foreach step, but i need to have comparison with list entries `OR` together, could you help me.

Comment: This will work the same as an or, the key is to append to matchingOrganisms for each loop iteration. Something like: matchingOrganisms.AddRange(...) then add then end of the loop you will have all matches.